# Enum after Exclude<> in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, enums, typescript-generics

I'm trying to have a sub-enum from another enum in typescript,  I found this example

```
const enum Errcode{
    Ok=0,
    Error=1,
    AccessDeny=201,
    PostsNotFound=202,
    TagNotFound=203,
    //...
}

type SuccessErrcode = Errcode.Ok;
type NotFoundError = Errcode.PostsNotFound|Errcode.TagNotFound;
type ErrorErrcode = Exclude<Errcode, Errcode.Ok>;
```

the thing is that now `ErrorErrcode` is a type and not an enum anymore, and I can't use it anymore otherwise I get the error message `ErrorErrcode only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`

How can I make an Enum from this union type?

Comment: Don't you want to do this? `const test: ErrorErrcode = Errcode.AccessDeny;`

Comment: You can't, you can get type from value but not the other way around

Comment: But you can use objects instead https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAogJwaAJgUwjAvDA3gWACgYT4kQEAuGARgBojSYBBYYDCAETTAE9qATAAZ6jUgAUQ0CADkQUAGIgArmBSChAhsVIAVAIYBzOYpVqNAZm1MA9DYB0jogF8Y+zKEhQiRT9BYANgEAwiDomDgEOiQA8gDW1ELWpI72iMhhGC5uHuDQQA

Comment: @GuerricP no, I want to create another  enum using the original enum without having to re-assign all the properties one by one

Comment: Like @AlekseyL. said you can infer a type from a value but not a new value from a type.

Comment: So Is it not possible to get a subset of values from an enum? @GuerricP

Comment: No the best thing you could do is to use the syntax I suggested in my first comment, which uses a `type` that refers to the runtime `enum`. TypeScript doesn't allow to generate a runtime `enum` from another.

Comment: Note that `const test: ErrorErrcode = Errcode.AccessDeny;` works just fine; why do you need it to be a different object?  TypeScript does not have any way of generating enums programmatically; if you want an enum you have to declare it yourself. Since `Errcode` is a `const enum` it doesn't even exist at runtime as an object, so there's nothing you can really do.  If you made it a plain non-`const` enum then you could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLL8Am) at least.  If any of that is useful as an answer I could write it up. Let me know.

Comment: You can't compute enums from mapped types.